# Load Dojo form from ajax call

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, dojo

I am trying to implement something like this.
http://app.maqetta.org/mixloginstatic/LoginWindow.html

I want the login page to load but if you click the signup button then an ajax will replace the  login form with the signup form.

I have got this to work using this code

```
dojo.xhrGet({
        // The URL of the request
        url: "'.$url.'",
        // The success callback with result from server
        load: function(newContent) {
            dojo.byId("'.$contentNode.'").innerHTML = newContent;
        },
        // The error handler
        error: function() {
            // Do nothing -- keep old content there
        }
    });'
```

the only problem is the new form just loads up as a normal form, not a dojo form.  I have tried to return some script with the phaser but it doesnt do anything.

```
<div id="loginBox"><div class="instructionBox">Please enter your details below and click <a><strong>signup</strong>
    </a> to have an activation email sent to you.</div>
    <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="site-form login-form" action="/user/signup" method="post"><div>
    <dt id="emailaddress-label"><label for="emailaddress" class="required">Email address</label></dt>
    <dd>
    <input 0="Errors" id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress" value="" type="text"></dd>
    <dt id="password-label"><label for="password" class="required">Password</label></dt>
    <dd>
    <input 0="Errors" id="password" name="password" value="" type="password"></dd>
    <dt id="captcha-input-label"><label for="captcha-input" class="required">Captcha Code</label></dt>
    <dd id="captcha-element">
    <img width="200" height="50" alt="" src="/captcha/d7849e6f0b95cad032db35e1a853c8f6.png">
    <input type="hidden" name="captcha[id]" value="d7849e6f0b95cad032db35e1a853c8f6" id="captcha-id">
    <input type="text" name="captcha[input]" id="captcha-input" value="">
    <p class="description">Enter the characters shown into the field.</p></dd>
    <dt id="submitButton-label">&nbsp;</dt><dd id="submitButton-element">
    <input id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="Signup" type="submit"></dd>
    <dt id="cancelButton-label">&nbsp;</dt><dd id="cancelButton-element">
    <button name="cancelButton" id="cancelButton" type="button">Cancel</button></dd> 
       </div></form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

                var widget  = dijit.byId("signup");

                if (widget) {
                   widget.destroyRecursive(true);
                } 

                dojo.parser.instantiate([dojo.byId("loginBox")]); 
                dojo.parser.parse(dojo.byId("loginBox"));
            });

            </script></div>
```

any advice on how i can get this to load as a dojo form. by the way i am using Zend_Dojo_Form, if i run the code directly then everything works find but through ajax it doesnt work. thanks.

---

update

I have discovered that if I load the form in my action and run the __toString() on it it works when i load the form from ajax.  It must do preparation in __toString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly; You need to run the dojo parser on html, for it to accept the data-dojo-type (fka dojoType) attributes, like so:

```
dojo.parser.parse( dojo.byId("'.$contentNode.'") )
```

This will of course only instantiate dijits where the dojo type is set to something, for instance (for html5 1.7+ syntax) `<form data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" action="index.php"> ... <button type="submit" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">Send</button> ... </form>`.

So you need to change the ajax contents which is set to innerHTML, so that the parser reckognizes the form of the type dijit.form.Form. That said, I urge people into using a complete set of dijit.form.* Elements as input fields.

In regards to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

This function will never get called. The `document`, youre adding innerHTML to, was ready perhaps a long time a go.

About Zend in this issue:

Youre most likely rendering the above output form from a `Zend_` Dojo type form. If the renderer is set as `programmatic`, you will see above html a script containing a registry for ID=>dojoType mappings. The behavior when inserting `<script>` as an innerHTML attribute value, the script is not run under most circumstances (!).

You should try something similar to this pseudo for your form controller:

if request is ajax dojoHelper set layout `declarative`
else dojoHelper set layout `programmatic`